# Trying to find a way to limit the number of List<Task> that can run at one time

Tags: async-await, ffmpeg, task, semaphore

My application has a List of Tasks.  Each Task launches a FFMPEG process that requires a lot of resources on my machine.  At times, this list can contain 200+ processes to FFMPEG.  While processing, my memory is at 99% and everything freezes up.

I need to limit the amount of processes that can run at one time.  I have read a little about SemaphoreSlim; however, I cannot wrap my mind around it's implementation.

Is this a solution for this particular problem and if so, any ideas on how to implement it in my code?

Below is my code:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task GetVideoFiles()
{            
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        AllSplices.Clear();
        AllSplices = new ObservableCollection<SpliceModel>();
        IsBusy = true;
        IsBusyMessage = "Extracting Metadata";
        IsBusyBackgroundVisible = "Visible";
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusyMessage));
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusyBackgroundVisible));
        metaTasks = new List<Task<VideoFileModel>>();                
        extractFramesTask = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();
        
        foreach (string file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
            bool canAdd = true;
            var tempFileName = fileInfo.Name;
            
            foreach (var video in AllVideos)
            {
                if (file == video.VideoPath)
                {
                    canAdd = false;
                    break;
                }

                if (video.VideoName.Contains(tempFileName))
                {
                    video.VideoName = "_" + video.VideoName;                            
                }                        
            }
            if (canAdd)
            {                        
                metaTasks.Add(System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => ProcessMetaData(file)));                        
            }                       
        }
        var metaDataResults = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(metaTasks);              
        
        foreach (var vid in metaDataResults)
        {                    
            if(vid == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            
            vid.IsNewVideo = true;                    
            AllVideos.Add(vid);
            
            // This list of task launches up to 200 video processing processes to FFMPEG
            extractFramesTask.Add(System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => ExtractFrames(vid)));
            
            vid.IsProgressVisible = "Visible";
            TotalDuration += vid.VideoDuration;
            vid.NumberOfFrames = Convert.ToInt32(vid.VideoDuration.TotalSeconds * 30);
            _ = ReportProgress(vid);
        }
       
        IsBusyMessage = "Importing Frames";
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusyMessage));                              
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(extractFramesTask);              
    }
```

Comment: The problem is with the extractFramesTask portion of the code

Comment: Have you tried an `ActionBlock`?

Comment: I have not tried ActionBlock.  I will look into it.  Thanks!